# Find the Missing Members of this Family

Tags: knowledge

Who are the Missing Members?

$?$, $V$, $U$, $?$,  $S$, $?$, $P$, $O$, $N$, $?$, $H$, $F$, $?$, $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing members are:

> Y, W, K, I, C

Making the full sequence:

> Y, V, U, W, S, K, P, O, N, I, H, F, C, B

Because these are:

> The one-letter chemical element abbreviations from the Periodic Table, when the full names are arranged in reverse alphabetical order: Yttrium (Y), Vanadium (V), Uranium (U), Tungsten (W), Sulfur (S), Potassium (K), Phosphorus (P), Oxygen (O), Nitrogen (N), Iodine (I), Hydrogen (H), Fluorine (F), Carbon (C), Boron (B).

Comment: Congrats!...must be good in chemistry

Comment: One of my faves! Far better than at formatting my answers...!

Comment: (Not knocking your answer but why is your 2nd letter 4th overall and not 2nd overall @Uvc ?)

Comment: @El-Guest Because the order is based on the *full name* of the element rather than just the symbol :) Translate the W as 'Tungsten' and it slots in 4th in the sequence, behind Yttrium, Vanadium and Uranium.